# how to update only modified values in spring mvc from spring form

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-form

I am displaying checkboxes on a page and want to only update values in the db for which the values were changed. Also I would like to display an error if nothing was changed and form was submitted.

This is what i have so far. Any suggestion?

**View**

```
public class PersonView {

    private List<Person> personList;

    public List<Person> getPersonList() {
        return personList;
    }

    public void setPersonList(List<Person> personList) {
        this.personList = personList;
    }
}
```

**Domain**

```
public class Person {

    private String fullName; 
    private Boolean isSupervisor;
    private Boolean isManager;

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public Boolean isSupervisor() {
        return isSupervisor;
    }

    public void setSupervisor(Boolean isSupervisor) {
        this.isSupervisor = isSupervisor;
    }

    public Boolean isManager() {
        return isManager;
    }

    public void setManager(Boolean isManager) {
        this.isManager = isManager;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/person.html")
public class PersonsController {

    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String initForm() {
        return "member";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String submitForm(@ModelAttribute PersonView personView) {
        model.addAttribute("persons", personView);
        return "successMember";
    }

    @ModelAttribute
    public PersonView getPersonView(){
        List<Person>  persons= personService.getPersonList();
        PersonView pv = new PersonView();
        pv.setPersonList(persons);

        return pv;
    }
}
```

**JSP**

```
<html>
<title>Persons Information</title>
</head>

<body>

    <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="personView">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Full Name</th>
                <th>Supervisor</th>
                <th>Manager</th>
            </tr>

            <c:forEach var="person" items="${personView.personList}"
                varStatus="row">
                <tr>
                    <td>{person.fullName}</td>
                    <td><form:checkbox path="personList[row.index].supervisor"  value="true" />
                    </td>
                    <td><form:checkbox path="personList[row.index].manager"     value="true" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>


            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Assuming you use JPA the updates are already handled, if you really want only the fields in the update that are updated (assuming you are using hibernate > 4.0) add `@DynamicUpdate`  to your entity.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i am not using hibernate at the moment. Just want to get the modified values and only update those which were modified etc.

Comment: Well then the short answer is you cannot unless you keep the old object, compare it with the new object and determine what to execute. When have 3 fields it is not that hard if you have many and nested fields it become a hard and tedious task.